# PHP form firing blanks

Tags: php, html, forms, email, web

My PHP form is sending me blank emails.

I'm not sure where the issue is and wondered if anyone would be kind enough to help out.

Here's the HTML

```
                <div class="form">
            <form method="post" action="send_contact.php">
                <div class="form_row">
                <label>Your Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="main_input" />
                </div>

                <div class="form_row">
                <label>Your Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="main_input" />
                </div>
                <div class="form_row">
                <label>Type of Inquiry:</label>
                <input type="text" name="inquiry" class="main_input" />
                </div>  

                <div class="form_row">
                <label>Your Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" class="main_textarea"></textarea>
                </div> 

                <div class="form_row">
                 <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" >
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
```

Here's the PHP

```
<?php

$subject = "$inquiry";

$message = "$message";


$mail_from = "$email";

$header = "from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='inquiries@openrhythmnetwork.com';

$send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Literally, all I'm receiving is a blank email with no subject heading...

Comment: The first thing to do is to put the following at the top of your page: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors',1);` and that way when something like this happens, PHP will complain at you.

Comment: Where did you learn to write code this way? I ask because http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php has been removed a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has been tested and working on my server. PHP Version 5.4

PHP (send_contact.php)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['inquiry'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];

$header = "From: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='email@example.com'; // change to your Email address

$send_contact = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've received your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

HTML form:

```
    <div class="form">
<form method="post" action="send_contact.php">
    <div class="form_row">
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="main_input" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
    <label>Your Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="main_input" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
    <label>Type of Inquiry:</label>
    <input type="text" name="inquiry" class="main_input" />
    </div>  

    <div class="form_row">
    <label>Your Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" class="main_textarea"></textarea>
    </div> 

    <div class="form_row">
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" >
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using variables like `$_POST['inquiry']` to access the post data.

Incidentally, using raw user data in an email is a good way to have your script turned into a spam system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection

Answer (score 2):

You need to use $_POST array variables to access the POSTed info from a form, like this:

```
$subject = $_POST['inquiry'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_from = $_POST['email'];
```

It would also be wise to read this now legendary post about [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign variable from `$_POST` array

```
$subject = htmlentities($_POST['inquiry']);
// and so on
```